# Using SCons to initialize and update Git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, scons

We use SCons and Git submodules to organize and build a software stack. We have several application developers who use our stack to build their applications on top of it. In order to minimize the friction from using our stack, what is the neatest way of using SCons to check if the submodules are initialized and up-to date and subsequently recursively update them?

The aim is to have the `scons` command do all the work.

My current current approach is:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["git", "submodule", "update", "--init", "--recursive"])
```

Comment: Please take into account that SCons is working file-oriented, not task-oriented. We see a lot of approaches like yours in our UserMailing list `scons-users@scons.org` (see http://scons.org/lists.html). People usually despair at the point where they're trying to get SCons to treat the result of the "git command" as target, i.e. what they're trying to express is " git-update module XYZ, and if it changed build it". This is not possible, because we expect our sources and targets to be files and directories only. Don't want to keep you from trying, just sayin' ;).

Comment: Thanks to the power of Python that SCons is based on, it is not overly difficult. I'll list the relevant parts of my solution in an answer below. But I do a agree, its not the build system's responsibility to handle these requirements

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025187/tell-scons-not-to-auto-create-directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant parts that are required to perform a recursive update on all submodules. This is useful for simplifying the default use-case, clone the repository and run `scons`

```
from subprocess import call

AddOption(
'--git',
type    = 'string',
nargs   = 1,
action  = 'store',
help    = 'use --git=no-sub-update to disable the submodule update')

## Update the git submodules
---------------------------------------------------
if GetOption('git') != 'no-sub-update':
    call(["git", "submodule", "update", "--init", "--recursive"])
```

Comment: Note that the update of the submodules will even get executed when calling SCons with the "`-n`" option...which is probably not a showstopper in your case, but one of the many intricacies arising from the fact that you didn't map the "git update" to a real SCons build step. ;)